# Android Google Maps v2 Stopping

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to Android and Google Maps v2 API. I tried to integrate the API in my app but I am getting:

> Unfortunately, Map Example has stopped.

Can anyone help me finding the mistake?

MainActivity class:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GoogleMap map;
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();

    if (map == null)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create Map.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else {
        // do somework here.

    }

    }

    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!-- Google Maps API V2 -->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Androidmainfest.xml

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>



 <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapexample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission                                   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Sample"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sample" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="6587000" />

    <!-- API KEY -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API-KEY-HERE" />
</application>
```

My logcat output

```
 06-10 21:03:06.610: E/dalvikvm(857): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment', referenced from method com.example.mapexample.MainActivity.onCreate
06-10 21:03:06.610: W/dalvikvm(857): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1271 (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment;) in Lcom/example/mapexample/MainActivity;
06-10 21:03:06.610: D/dalvikvm(857): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0014
06-10 21:03:06.670: D/AndroidRuntime(857): Shutting down VM
06-10 21:03:06.670: W/dalvikvm(857): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ae6d70)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Process: com.example.mapexample, PID: 857
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapexample/com.example.mapexample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.example.mapexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 11 more
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4788)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 21 more
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mapexample-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mapexample-1, /system/lib]]
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
06-10 21:03:06.880: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 24 more
```

Comment: If you could please post your logcat, probably an api  key issue or something but easier to tell from the log

Comment: device or emulator ?

Comment: Probably a good idea to not post your API key on the internet...

Comment: ok sir..in that code have any mistake sir

Comment: in my device its map is not coming

Comment: Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

ClassNotFoundException, so mostly you have missed adding the library dependency. The Google Play Services need to be setup before using them into your project. Find details in the following link:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

As per official documentation here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, the minimum required sdk version is 12. Please try increasing your minSdkVersion value to 12.

Comment: min sdk 12 and max sdk 12 we want to give.. if we give like that means how that maps will work for 4.4.4.. sir this one also not working sir

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. You may try this way, This is mentioned in the official docs,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setUpMapIfNeeded()

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
}

@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // map has been loaded
    }
```

Make sure your class implements **OnMapReadyCallback**