# I am working with Google Map api in Android geting unfortanly app was stopped

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-fragments

I have been working on Google Maps, but I am getting

> Unfortunately, APP was stopped.

I am given all permissions and Google play services. This error is being shown in my LogCat which I have shown below.

```
 06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Process: com.example.onroad, PID: 851
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.onroad/com.example.onroad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:309)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at com.example.onroad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 11 more
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4788)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 21 more
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.onroad-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.onroad-2, /system/lib]]
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
06-11 16:05:48.050: E/AndroidRuntime(851):  ... 24 more
```

Comment: Please Clearly Say the Question. Not the error message

Comment: i am not getting the google maps in android sir, i given all fields but also not getting output i am getting unforutly app was stopped. i written the code like this sir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767104/can-anyone-help-me-on-google-maps-api-in-android-how-to-work

Comment: have you create google console app

Comment: yes sir for that only i get google map api key

Comment: Hope! You have confused, Try to follow this stuff. It really guide you to accomplish the task.  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
If you like just put up on this command

Comment: i did like this sir.. this link also mine only sir there i not get any reponse sir plzz help me sir i am working from last 4 days onwards http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767104/can-anyone-help-me-on-google-maps-api-in-android-how-to-work   infact i am not getting were i did mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check did you really created your app project on Google Developers console?..
Learn from here about [Google Developers Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Also Check your manifest file that you properly add all permissions and mata data.

Error Also Shows that you didn't add "Google Play Services" to your project.
download them from your SDK MANAGER and add it in your project's dependencies

Comment: did you add the Google Play Services to your project?

Comment: yes sir from adt-> sdk->extras->google->libproject->google play services lib

Comment: ok i am not getting were i did mistake in my project but i think i hope i given all credentials on my code plzz help me i am straguling from last 4 days onwards

Comment: First download Google play services from SDK manager 
add it in your project
register your project at google developers console

Comment: follow this tutorial it will guide you properly

Comment: follow this tutorial it will guide you properly
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/